# ESP32 USB HID/MIDI library (not the BLE one)

Tags: esp32, midi, hid

I couldn't find any library to use an "old" ESP32 (not the new ESP32-S2) as an HID connected physicaly to the Usb port (not over BLE pairing) to send keystrokes to the PC ...
Is there any solution? Any code example, so far?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ... MIDI is used for musical instruments

Comment: Esp32 doesn't have usb.

Comment: @jsotola i am trying to send keystrokes to the PC by plugging the (old) ESP32 on to the Usb port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESP32 doesn't have USB. You can't do USB communication. All it has is (like the UNO) a USB to UART interface chip. Unlike the UNO this is *not* programmable (more like a cheap Chinese knock-off UNO clone in that respect).

You would need to couple it with a microcontroller that *has* USB and program *hat* to be your USB interface and communicate with it over some other communication medium, such as UART or I2C.